# XE8 Run is Stuck Launching for C++ Android for New Apps or Samples

Tags: android, ide, c++builder, c++builder-xe8

I have spent hours trying to resolve this issue (including Embarcadero forums and google). Apparently there was a bunch of posts lost on the EDN?. Here is the issue:

I have C++ Android apps that compiled on XE6 that I have migrated over to XE8. With the exception of access violations being thrown now when apps exit (I will post as a seperate issue) the apps launch and the IDE is aware that the app has successfully launched. Both Release and Debug work fine. So why do new apps or sample apps freeze the IDE, regardless of Debug or Release? The "Run" dialog is stuck on the Launching stage, even though the app runs on the Android device. I am using the Galaxy S4 with 4.4.4. After exiting the app on the Android device, the "Run" box stays and the IDE freezes. I tried to duplicate project settings, but may have missed something. Still, a new project should "work". Any thoughts?

BTW (for those watching this post from Embarcadero): The new community.embarcadero.com post method does not work. It tells me the content is empty when it is not. Word counter stays at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. Here is what worked for me:

Add the following to the Run Parameters for Android:

-cleaninstall -debugport=54321  (this number can be changed)

Even when restarting the phone and IDE doesn't work, the above change does, at least so far.

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.template.xml
between

```
</activity>
```

`<%activity%>`

I insert:

```
    <!-- shryu -->
            <activity android:name="com.lamerman.TabbedApplication"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" />
```

where TabbedApplication is my app name.

After this I compile and rub debugger and this work !!!